# CakePHP 3 application working slow when Implemented Redis cache

Tags: php, redis, cakephp-3.0

My Cake Application works very slow when I have implemented the Radis cache.
If I Remove Redis Cache from the configuration then it works very fast.

Example:

- Without Redis cache one post request takes 2 seconds to complete the request.
- With Redis cache same post request takes 20 seconds to complete the request.

Can anyone have any idea that why cake application works very slow when I use redis cache?

Comment: If you send the same POST request for a second time, is it quicker?

Comment: Yes. without cache configuration, it works very quick,

Comment: Ankit, please switch on the caching and try sending the same POST twice. Is the second POST quicker than the first?

Comment: No, Same time takes second request.

Comment: Can you explain what your POST does? Maybe with some code chunks?